# format does not match error-cannot convert string data to datetime format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert it to datetime format. but i keep getting the following error.

```
convert_datetime= "Jun 25, 2021 10:35:50".replace(',','')

print(datetime.strptime(convert_datetime," %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

**Error:**

raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data 'Jun 25 2021 10:35:50' does not match format ' %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the formatted string you are trying to match with in the strptime function.
Change

```
" %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"
```

to

```
"%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"
```

. The space before the %b is causing the error because you do not have a space before Jun in convert_datetime variable.
Now your code modifies to:

```
convert_datetime= "Jun 25, 2021 10:35:50".replace(',','')
print(datetime.strptime(convert_datetime,"%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

This should be working fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
datetime.strptime(convert_datetime,"%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

You've an extra space at the beginning of the strp string.

Answer (score 1):

**strptime** function of **datetime** module takes two arguments **date_string** and **format**

In your case, date_string is fine but format string is malformed. " %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S" should be "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S".

As per documentation,

*ValueError is raised if the date_string and format can’t be parsed by time.strptime() or if it returns a value which isn’t a time tuple. For a complete list of formatting directives, see strftime() and strptime() Behavior.*

[Python Official Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)